# How to solve Message: Trying to get property of non-object error in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm very fresher in CodeIgniter and practicing. I'm now developing a simple Codeigniter application just for practicing. I've Banks and its branches in the database. I just want to show branches with its bank name. Branches are showing but in the controller while getting banks, this error is showing. I tried these in SO [links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Trying%20to%20get%20property%20of%20non-object%20codeigniter), but nothing found works.

```
"A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

in Line Number: 85 and 91
```

**This is my controller**

```
function ShowBranchList() {

            $branch_list = $this->FD_Model->get_all_branches();
            $get_bank =   $this->FD_Model->get_bank_by_branch($branch_list->bankid); //This is Line Number 85
            if($branch_list ){
            $data = array(
                'pagetitle' => 'Branch List View',
                'branch_list_data' => $branch_list,
                'br_bank' => $get_bank['bank_name'],//This is Line Number 93
            );

        }
```

**Model**

```
/*function for getting all branches*/

function get_all_branches() {
    $this->db->order_by( $this->brid, $this->order );
    return $this->db->get( $this->brtable )->result();
}


/*function for getting banks by branches*/

function get_bank_by_branch( $id ) {
        $this->db->where( $this->bid, $id);
        return $this->db->get( $this->banktable )->row();
    }
```

And finally, this is my **View**

```
 foreach ($branch_list_data as $branch_list) 
        { 
          <?php echo $branch_list->brname ?>
          <?php echo $br_bank; ?>
        }
```

Anyone know the issue?

**Update**

When I'm tring to view the query

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

**Result**

> SELECT * FROM `tbl_bankmaster` WHERE `bid` IS NULL

The value `$branch_list->bankid` is `null`.When I'm hardcoding some values the view page is showing without any error.

Comment: Line number ?? post complete error

Comment: read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: I've added the line.Please check my updated question.

Comment: @SudhiSr check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
$get_bank =   $this->FD_Model->get_bank_by_branch($branch_list[0]->bankid);
```

**AND**

```
'br_bank' => $get_bank[0]->bank_name # this will work maybe
```

or

```
'br_bank' => $get_bank[0]['bank_name']
```

> **Its `0` indexed array so you need to add the key to access the child's**

Comment: There is error in  `$get_bank = $this->FD_Model->get_bank_by_branch($branch_list->bankid);` . I think `$branch_list->bankid` is null. That is the actual problem. When I'm tring to hardcode bankid value, view page is working finely.

Comment: @SudhiSr use this `$branch_list[0]->bankid` **check it carefully**

Comment: Is there any changes in return type in model?

Comment: just keep it as it is and change controller codes what i have mentioned

Comment: I think you're on the right way. Now query returns the value, but there is error in `'br_bank' => $get_bank[0]->bank_name` . **The error is Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in** this line `'br_bank' => $get_bank[0]->bank_name` I tried `'br_bank' => $get_bank[0]['bank_name']` also. The error is same.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) . The [problem is solved now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271656/6166417).

Answer (score 0):

Change your data in view like this

```
foreach ($branch_list_data as $branch_list) 
{ 
   echo $branch_list['brname']; //change your data like this
   echo $br_bank; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've no problem while getting branches. I've error while fetching brank from branches. Here,  `$get_bank =   $this->FD_Model->get_bank_by_branch($branch_list->bankid);`

Answer (score 0):

I finally make it happen with the help of [Abdulla Nilam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271079/6166417)'s answer. I just passed the value in array like

```
'br_bank' => $get_bank->bank_name
```

Now the view is working.

Answer (score -1):

`get_bank_by_branch($branch_list->bankid);` This method returning only object.
`$get_bank` this variable you're accessing by an array, but it's an object.